# JSON/jQuery/PHP : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

UPDATED :  now I can see datas are loaded (from F12 > Network on Chrome). But spans are not updated with datas loaded from JSON :(

I've error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token", but after hours of searching and tests I don't know why.

index.html head :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var displayResult = function(response){
        $("#fruit_name").append(response.fruit_name);
        $("#fruit_color").append(response.fruit_details.Color);
        $("#fruit_taste").append(response.fruit_details.Taste);
    }
    var response = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType:"json",
    url: "https://www.domain.tld/api/?core=fruits&function=getFruits",
    data: "",
    success: displayResult
});
</script>
```

index.html body :

```
<p>Fruit name : <span id="fruit_name"></span></p>
<p>Fruit color : <span id="fruit_color"></span></p>
<p>Fruit taste : <span id="fruit_taste"></span></p>
```

api file (PHP) :

```
$array = array(
            "fruit_name" => "Tomato",
                "fruit_details" => array(
                    "Color" => "red",
                    "Taste" => "acid"
                )
            );
echo json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

api raw return :

```
{"fruit_name":"Tomato","fruit_details":{"Color":"red","Taste":"acid"}}
```

Can someone help me ?

Content JSON send as Content-Type: application/json

Thank you.

Comment: missing semi colons on lines 4 & 5

Comment: Error when copy/paste, updated ;)

Comment: looks fine... which is the line pointed out by browser console

Comment: do you have a line number of where the error is occuring?

Comment: Where and when you got the error

Comment: line 1 : {"fruit_name":"Tomato","fruit_details":{"Color":"red","Taste":"acid"}}

Comment: What you have is JSON, not JSONP. To make a cross-origin ajax request for JSON, the JSON must be returned wrapped in the passed callback.

Comment: Is this JavaScript also located on `https://www.domain.tld`?

Comment: It should be `fruit_details` instead of `fruits_details` in your `displayResult` function.

Comment: Thank you matewka, but same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> url: "https://www.domain.tld/api/?core=fruits&function=getFruits&callback=?",
> ```

You're using a `callback` parameter in your url, which means that [jQuery will treat it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as a [JSONP call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) - where your response is invalid. Remove it, and your response will be properly parsed as JSON:

```
url: "https://www.domain.tld/api/?core=fruits&function=getFruits",
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I've edited from JSONP to JSON by removing "&callback=?". Now I don't have error from console but span is not updated with datas loaded :/

Comment: Ok now I can see datas are loaded (from F12 > Network on Chrome). But spans are not updated with datas loaded from JSON :(

Comment: Then try to log the jQuery objects and the `response` argument to get sure

Answer (score -1):

This is jQuery code:

```
$("#fruit_name" ).val(response.fruit_name);
$("#fruit_color" ).val(response.fruit_color);
$("#fruit_taste" ).val(response.fruit_taste);
```

Make sure it is enclosed with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fruit_name" ).val(response.fruit_name);
    $("#fruit_color" ).val(response.fruit_color);
    $("#fruit_taste" ).val(response.fruit_taste);
});
```

Comment: Of course it won't change, it's already inside a `$(document).ready()` call (and being passed as the success callback of an AJAX request).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist tell me please, how could I know that the code was already inside `$(document).ready()`?? OP didn't provide it in the question.

Comment: @matewka It looks like the question has been edited back and forth; there was a `$(document).ready(` line in there when I read the question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist if so, please be that kind and undo your downvote (if one of them was yours, of course).